# Set cookie inside AuthorizedAttribute's OnAuthentication

Tags: c#, .net

I inherited a code that is written in .NET framework and it uses the System.Web.Http.AuthorizedAttribute for authentication.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
       // 1. Extract action context request header authorization for basic user name and password information
       // 2. Validate this against the database.
       // 3. If validated, call SetPrincipal() and IsAuthorized()
}
```

So far this is working great, the request to a controller will get authenticated every time, the controller will then do the work to generate the data to send back in the response.

Well, I want to use JWT Token framework;  I prefer to use .NET Core but since this application is written in .NET framework I need to make it work with OnAuthorization.  So here is my implementation:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
   // 1. Extract action context request header authorization for basic user name and password information
   // 2. Validate this against the database.
   // 3. If validated, generate a JWT Token.
   // 4. put this token in the response's cookie to send back to the client.
 }
```

Right now, when I set the response cookie inside the OnAuthorization(), it immediately returns the request with the cookie to the client.

The problem with this is the client now has to make two separate requests, one to authenticate to get the JWT Token from me and then use that token in the next request.  How can I do this in one single request which is to authenticate, get the token, process the request in the controller and then set the cookie for the JWT Token?

My code of setting the cookie in the OnAuthorization is as follow:

```
 var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("jwtToken", generatedToken);
 cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
 cookie.Domain = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Host;
 actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
 actionContext.Response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
```

Can you point me to the right approach? where should I set my cookie? I am doing it in OnAuthorization() because that is where I invoke the coke to validate and generate JWT Token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem, but ideally the OnAuthorization should not be overridden. Instead, you should override the IsAuthorized method, that is called by the OnAuthorization. Check the OnAuthorization implementation below.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
    }

    if (SkipAuthorization(actionContext))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext))
    {
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}
```